# How do I uninstall Google Chrome in Fedora?

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, gnome3

Yesterday I installed Fedora 15 Beta with GNOME 3 - it works well. One problem though is that I installed Chrome 32-bit (which was wrong, should have been the 64-bit version) and now I can't uninstall it.

I can't find it in Add/Remove Software, and I also can't install the correct version of Chrome because it complains about my other copy of Chrome.

Any ideas how I can remove the existing copy and get the 64-bit version installed?

Here's the message I get when trying to install:

```
Test Transaction Errors:   file /etc/cron.daily/google-chrome from install of google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.x86_64 conflicts with file from package google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.i386
  file /opt/google/chrome/chrome from install of google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.x86_64 conflicts with file from package google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.i386
  file /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox from install of google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.x86_64 conflicts with file from package google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.i386
  file /opt/google/chrome/libffmpegsumo.so from install of google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.x86_64 conflicts with file from package google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.i386
  file /opt/google/chrome/libpdf.so from install of google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.x86_64 conflicts with file from package google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.i386
  file /opt/google/chrome/libppGoogleNaClPluginChrome.so from install of google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.x8...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up a terminal, and enter:

```
rpm -qa | grep chrome
```

Look to see if you can find the installed Chrome package, and if you find it, enter:

```
rpm -e <chrome package name here>
```

For example:

```
rpm -e google-chrome-stable-22.0.1229.94-161065.i386
```

If you're looking for where the files are located, it may be different depending on a distro, but you can start by checking [the popular answer here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5708e7168a5f9695&hl=en).

Comment: Hm, thank you! I found google chrome and when I tried rpm -e ... it says "package google-chrome-stable-11.0.696.65-84435.i368 is not installed"

Comment: Very strange. Can you try `rpm --rebuilddb`, then double check `rpm -qa` to see if it's still there, then try the uninstall again? Make sure you spelled the package correctly ;)

Not sure this would help either, but you could also try the `rpm -e --nodeps` flag, to ignore dependencies. 

If this doesn't work, for the x64 install, you can try adding the --force switch to see if it will overwrite 32's files.

Comment: Haha damnit! I spelled it wrong :/ It works now, had to use sudo tho. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. And the worst of us. Pretty much all of us. Glad it's working for you now though.

Comment: Thanks and stay tuned, I'm sure there will be more questions soon...he he

Comment: Also, if you run into issues and you don't get a quick or decisive answer from superuser, try hitting up http://unix.stackexchange.com/
It's a bit more focused so you will have more nix gurus looking at it (and not just Linux peons like myself :)

Comment: Thank you! `rpm -qa | grep chrome` can be handy here.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type (as root):

```
yum -y erase google-chrome
```

Or if you are a *sudoer*, type:

```
sudo yum -y erase google-chrome
```

And that will remove Chrome from your system.

Comment: I get:

`Error: Could not find xdg-icon-resource
error: %preun(google-chrome-stable-72.0.3626.81-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1`

`Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package google-chrome-stable-72.0.3626.81-1.x86_64`

Comment: I had to do: `sudo yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts erase google-chrome`

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I was able to remove it from CentOS 6.2:

```
[root@I7 ~]# rpm -qa | grep chrome
xorg-x11-drv-openchrome-0.3.0-3.20120806git.el6.x86_64

[root@I7 ~]# yum -y erase xorg-x11-drv-openchrome-0.3.0-3.20120806git.el6.x86_64
```

In some distributions, the package included instead might be chromium (grepping for `chrom`, not `chrome`):

```
$ use rpm -qa | grep chrom
chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: I also needed to use this option: `--setopt=stflags=noscripts`, otherwise this error appeared: `Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package google-chrome-stable
Error: Could not find xdg-icon-resource`

Answer (score 0):

Installing xdg-utils first, and then removing google-chrome did the trick for me:

1. yum install xdg-utils
2. yum remove google-chrome
3. yum remove xdg-utils

Answer (score -1):

the second post, which says

> yum -y erase google-chrome
>
> Or if you are a sudoer, type:
>
> sudo yum -y erase google-chrome
>
> And that will remove Chrome from your system.

is the better way than the other post.  while both will do the job, yum is the preferred method over rpm, as it is a smart frontend for the rpm package manager, and will correct any dependency mistakes automatically, which rpm cannot.